# How can I statically declare a function with custom properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to declare a function with custom properties *statically*? It's trivial to dynamically add the properties after the function is declared, but I want to know if this can be done statically, so as to remain compatible with TypeScript interfaces using said shape:

```js
const functionWithCustomProperties: {
  (): 'foo';
  customProperty: 'bar';
} = /* is this possible? */
```